# What do square brackets enclosed in normal brackets do?

Tags: python

For example in the computer variable, what purpose do the square brackets enclosed by the normal brackets server? I am new to python and confused about this. Thanks in advance!

```
import random

def play():
    user = input(" 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors: ")
    computer = random.choice(['r', 'p', 's'])

    if user == computer:
        return "tie"
```

Comment: That is just passing a list of three letters as a parameter to the `random.choice` function.  The function chooses one and returns it.  It is just like `func(x)`, except that `x` is a literal list.

Comment: Square brackets represent a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)

Answer (score 1):

whenever you use squared brackets you are defining a list (an array)

when you call a function (like `random.choice` ) need to use () to pass arguments

so in this case you are calling a function over a list the equivalen should be:

```
def play():
    user = input(" 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors: ")
    myList = ['r','p','s']
    random.choice(myList)
     if user == computer:
         return "tie"
```

this is a paper scissor rock game where the only response is to tie. the random.choice function select one element from an input List

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets are actually a very simple term in python known as a list.

The code above could also translate to:

```py
import random #Import random module

userinput = input(" 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors: ") #ask user what they want to input
choicelist = ['r', 'p', 's'] #List of options
computer = random.choice(choicelist) #pick a random option from list

if user == computer: #checking if they are both the same
    print("tie") #return tie if equal (Also this was a return which only works in functions, but i removed the function because it was not needed)
```

Please comment if you have any more questions!

Comment: You are using `random.choice()`. I think you meant to pass the list as an argument to the fnction here?

Comment: Oh yea, i forgot to add it after I modified it. Whoops!

Answer (score 0):

`function(a)` means, call the function `function` with the argument `a`.

`function([a])` means, call the function with the list `[a]` as its argument. Equivalently, you could write `function(list(a))`

Both characters have other uses; round parentheses can be used to group expressions, like in mathematics, which in Python also gets used to indicate a tuple. So,

`function((a,))` means, call the function with the tuple `(a,)` as the argument. The comma is necessary to make it into a tuple; just `(a)` is merely the mathematical grouping we mentioned before, saying evaluate `a` before ... nothing. Equivalently, you could write `function(tuple(a))`

Square brackets are also used in indexing, so `listvar[a]` means the `a`:th element of the list variable `listvar`, and `dictvar[a]` means get the value for the key `a` from the dictionary `dictvar`.

For lists, the notation actually allows you to pull out sublists, called *slices,* in various ways, like `listvar[:-a]` or `listvar[::]`. This is complex enough that I'll defer the explanation of it to a separate question: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Square brackets are also used for various matrix notations in Numpy and Pandas, but that's not part of the Python core.